# OSX 10.7 Apache can't do file uploads to local server

Tags: macos, permission, apache

I have Apache running on another machine on the local network but am unable to do certain things that I can on the live server - namely perform file uploads.

Wordpress tells me this may be because Apache doesn't have permissions to write to the website directories - does anyone know how to fix this?

The website folder is shared on the network also so I can't really go around `chmod`ing it incase I break access for someone else.

Any help appreciated

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: generally it's just an HTTP error depending on the uploader. Wordpress says "error creating directory [dir]. Is it writable by the server?" or words to that effect - I've already googled this ofcourse but found nothing helpful.

Comment: the error is the same nomatter what uploader or code I use to try and create or save a file on the server - wordpress is merely the most verbose of these when it fails so I used that as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a directory permissions issue. You should ensure that the folder you are uploading to allows read/write/execute access for the web user (typically _www).

In practice, this means you should change the owner and/or group of the folder, or allow read/write/execute for all:

```
chmod 777 /path/to/uploads
```

Comment: good to know the user, thanks. just one niggle - i can't seem to find a terminal on the server. do you happen to know where they hid it? or is it normally in plain view?

Comment: Do you have direct access to the server or are you logging in remotely? The server is running MacOS X right?

Comment: yes I have gui access, it's across the room, running osx 10.7

Comment: Then it should be at /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

Comment: aaahh found it. sorry that's my fault, eyes needing tested lol. thanks for your help, this worked.